# How to extract key and value from ConsumerRecord[String, String] in Scala

Tags: scala

While reading from Kafka message in we need to process each RDD object, and have to process the each message that is in form of ConsumerRecord[String, String] form. How to extract key and value from it.

Comment: The official [Spark Streaming + Kafka integration guide](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/streaming-kafka-0-10-integration.html) should answer your question.